# Changing method of data entry based on number of selections

Tags: list, select, autocomplete, boolean

This is more of a philosophical question, and most-likely I'll bet that there are many different opinions - I'd like to get input regarding all of your opinions.

Assume a large database with many different types of variables and many different types of "data" that would go into those variables.

Assuming a "Boolean" value 1/0, yes/no, true/false, male/female - I often use checkboxes or radio buttons - rarely if ever option lists.

For "medium-sized" lists of possibilities (names of 5 people, names of different cars, etc) I'll often use select lists - though I've used a select list for all 50 of the states.

For larger/longer lists I'll go to a jQuery autocomplete list, with local data (non-server).

My questions to you are:

1. Do you have a different approach to selecting methods for data input?
2. Do you have a specific "number" of elements at which you'll move from a select list to an autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it'll depend mostly on the application I'm building. Some applications already have certain input methods in place, in which case I often prefer consistency over alternative methods that might be better suited but make the application more chaotic.

With new applications my approach is pretty similar. Booleans often have checkboxes or radio buttons but select lists aren't uncommon either. For more options, select lists are also my preferred choice. When I have a large form with a good amount of select lists, I also to keep booleans in select lists as well in order to keep the form consistent. Having a bunch of select lists and then a checkbox may look a bit odd.

Long lists depend on the content. If searching by typing will improve user experience, an auto-complete list is often a good choice. Most browsers will also jump to a correct select list item when typing though, so I don't always see the use for auto-completion when users would generally type the first few letters of the item anyway.

For very long lists, I've made quite a few server queries for auto-completion as well. E.g., linking to one of 10000+ tickets. In this case, having a slight delay after a key-event before searching can prevent a large serverload.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for the excellent comments - so my thinking is not "out of the mainstream". Thanks!